# Timer in Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am writing a python app using Tkinter for buttons and graphics and having trouble getting a timer working, what I need is a sample app that has three buttons and a label.

[start timer]  [stop timer] [quit]

When I press the start button a function allows the label to count up from zero every 5 seconds, the stop button stops the timer and the quit button quits the app.

I need to be able to press stop timer and quit at any time, and the time.sleep(5) function locks everything up so I can't use that.

currently i'm using threading.timer(5,do_count_function) and getting nowhere !

I'm a vb.net programmer, so python is a bit new to me, but hey, i'm trying.

Answer (score 2):

Check the .after method of your Tk() object. This allows you to use Tk's timer to fire events within the gui's own loop by giving it a length of time and a callback method.